# Subtract Two Columns In SQL

Tags: sql

I'm drawing a blank,  I have this query that works perfectly, but now i want to only return

> TotalCredits - TotalDebits as Difference

Below is the query that produces the two values I need to subtract,  I played around with joins but I think i'm way off track.

```
select
(select sum(TOTALAMOUNT) from journal where memberid=48 and CREDIT =1) as TotalCredits,
(select SUM(totalamount) from Journal where MEMBERID=48 and DEBIT =1) As TotalDebits
```

Comment: Is this SQL Server syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your query into a derived table like this;

```
select TotalCredits - TotalDebits as Difference
from 
(
select
(select sum(TOTALAMOUNT) from journal where memberid=48 and CREDIT =1) as TotalCredits,
(select SUM(totalamount) from Journal where MEMBERID=48 and DEBIT =1) As TotalDebits
) temp
```

Comment: both answer were great and valuable, i chose @Dan because he returned only the difference field as i asked, but again both answers work.  I will be using other answer for other situations  Thanks for both replies help me out greatly.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN CREDIT = 1 THEN TOTALAMOUNT END) as TotalCredits,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DEBIT = 1 THEN TOTALAMOUNT END) as TotalDebits,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CREDIT = 1 THEN TOTALAMOUNT END) - SUM(CASE WHEN DEBIT = 1 THEN TOTALAMOUNT END) as Diff
FROM journal 
WHERE memberid=48
```